# how to remove the numbers and keep the rest after the dot

Tags: php

Sorry I couldn't explain clearly in the title. I Studied math in other language I don't know what it calls.

I have these values.

```
$input = 13.2156;
$input = 45.232;
$input = 1193.215624;
```

I want a function in PHP to get what what after the dot,
which is this case

```
$input = 13.2156;     // 0.2156
$input = 45.232;      // 0.232
$input = 1193.215624; // 0.215624
```

I know `intval()` do the opposite. **BUT** I want the opposite of the opposite. :D

Comment: Possibly `$input = $input - intval($input)`?

Comment: use intval to get the whole number then use modulus i.e. $integral = intval(3.1415); $result = 3.1415 % $integral;

Comment: or use @jonhopkins answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = $input - intval($input);
```

For negative numbers, the above code will get a negative decimal component (which may be desired in some cases). If you always want the positive decimal component, just take the absolute value of `$input`.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
    $input = $input - intval($input).

This leaves just the fraction.